# Re.sub regex delete nested brackets python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string and I would like to use a regex substitution in python that deletes the content of braces except for any number within parenthesis located after a `#` character and before a `.` character (3, in the example below), as well as any text within round parentheses comprised entirely of letters. ("info" in the example below)

I've put this together to solve the first problem but it's not working (I am an absolute beginner at regex).

```
string = 'Name, Other "Else" (2000) (info) {empty (#3.99)}'

r= re.sub(r'(^?={))?\{.+\(#(\d+)\.\d+\)\}','',string)
print r
```

the ideal output should be:

```
Name, Other "Else" (2000) (3)
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there some reason that `(info)` isn't included in the output?

Comment: "info" is within round brackets but since it's non-numerical it should be deleted

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r'\(\d*\D+\d*\)\s+','',re.sub(r'\{.+?\#(\d+)\.\d+\)}',r'(\1)',s))
```

What this does is match the number inside the braces, then use capturing (the part inside the brackets) to get the desired string.

sidenote: It's best not to use string as a name for variables, as this could conflict with the "string" module.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the curly braces part :)...how can I delete the content of round braces if not entirely made by numbers (a solution  with a separate regex is fine)?

Comment: Try the new version. And like Slater said add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the question